# How to apply style to the nested views in Android

Tags: android, layout, styles, textview, selector

Using an xml layout file with some part like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_drawable" >

    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And consideting that "custom_drawable" is a selector for different states (pressed, selected, etc.), I am wondering if it is possible to apply an style to the nested elements using the "custom_drawable". For example, changing the color of the TextView depending on the state of the RelativeLayout...

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:** I have found a way of doing it with just the XML files, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found a workaround to make it work with just the XML files. It consists in using the clause `android:duplicateParentState="true"` in the nested children views and that way the state is inherit from the parent view.

There is also the need of creating a new selector for controlling the text color/type, etc. But that is pretty simple.

One example using the initial code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_drawable" >

    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@drawable/custom_drawable_text"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

1. activity_main.xml

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <RadioGroup
           android:id="@+id/rdg"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/rdbOne"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/radio_selector_background"
               android:button="@null"
               android:checked="true"
               android:padding="2dp"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               android:text="One"
               android:textColor="@drawable/radio_selector_color" />
           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/rdbTwo"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/radio_selector_background"
               android:button="@null"
               android:padding="2dp"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               android:text="Two"
               android:textColor="@drawable/radio_selector_color" />
           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/rdbThree"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/radio_selector_background"
               android:button="@null"
               android:padding="2dp"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               android:text="Three"
               android:textColor="@drawable/radio_selector_color" />
       </RadioGroup>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. under drawable folder define  below two xml file.(for color and background selector)

   a. radio_selector_background.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:drawable="@color/orange" android:state_checked="true"></item>
       <item android:drawable="@color/white"></item>

   </selector>
   ```

   b. radio_selector_color.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true"></item>
      <item android:color="@color/orange" ></item>

   </selector>
   ```
3. under values folder define colors.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <color name="orange">#f04e23</color>
       <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
   </resources>
   ```

Comment: The idea is good, but the problem is that in my case I want to modify the style of the nested elements and you are just modifying two different propertied of the same element.

Answer (score 0):

```
btn1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
 btn2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ad321a"));
} else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
btn2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#Fad213"));
}
return false;
}
});
```

i have written this code for the two button 
when i press the button then it will change the color of the btn2
and when i release then it change its color again.

Comment: you can any thing like change color, change text appearance, and hide the other view. any thing which you want to do.

Comment: Yep, this is the way I already know, but I want to do it without code, just using the XML files... Thank you.

Comment: opps..!!
well i will do research for it that how to it using the xml.